# Как прочитать бинарный файл на kotlin

Tags: c++, kotlin

У меня есть бинарный файл, в котором записаны некоторые характеристики звёзд, в силу особенностей этих характеристик, поля записи не одинаковы. В c++ я могу прочитать файл следующим образом

```
ifstream file;
file.open(PATH, ios::in | ios::binary);    
int a;
file.read((char*)&a, sizeof(int));
```

Использовать функции вроде getline() не дают мне удобоваримых чисел, а только разные символы. Я хочу попробовать аналогичным образом прочитать файл в котлине. Я пробовал использовать классы FileInputStream и RandomAccessFile, но оба не работают так как надо. Каким образом я могу прочитать данные из файла? Ну и прошу объяснить почему тот код, который я привёл работает, а та же функция getline() - нет. (Интерес скорее спортивный, чем из необходимости, но всем спасибо за помощь)

Comment: getline не даёт "удобоваримых чисел" по одной простой причине он считывает данные до 0x10 числа оно же '\n' ну или конца фала если не встретил 0x10.

Comment: Тогда он должен выводить весь файл численно, но он либо вообще ничего не выводит, либо выводит не численные символы

Comment: с чего бы вдруг? getline рассматривает входные данные как ascii последовательность, он не конвертирует твои бинарные данные в строки. Если у тебя в файле лежит int‭[0x21 0x22 0x23 0x24]=555885348‬ то и в std::string который он вернёт будет `!"#$` а не `555885348‬`

Comment: можно создать строковой поток, читать байты туда, пока не встретите символ завершитель.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `getline` не предназначен для работы с бинарными файлами, только с текстовыми. 
Для чтения данных из бинарных файлов нужно использовать [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html):

```
import java.io.DataInputStream
import java.io.File

fun main() {
    val stream = DataInputStream(File("data.bin").inputStream())

    // Будет прочитано 4 байта и интерпретировано как знаковый int с порядком байт big endian:
    val i = stream.readInt();

    // Если нужно little endian:
    val j = Integer.reverseBytes(i)

    stream.close()

    println(i)
    println(j)
}
```

К примеру, если в файле 4 байта: `0A 00 00 00`

Вывод будет такой:

```
167772160
10
```

Детали работы подобных методов для других типов данных можно посмотреть в описании интерфейса [`DataInput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) (раздел "Method Detail"), реализацией которого является класс `DataInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

```
val fis = FileInputStream(file)
val bytes = ByteArray(fis.channel.size().toInt())
fis.read(bytes)
```